# Tailwind height transition with react

Tags: css, reactjs, transition

I'm using react and tailwind for my project. Both of them are latest version.
I want make a 500 ms transition when an element's height change like this :

```
className={`${simpleState ? "h-5" : "h-10"} transition duration-500 ease-in-out`}
```

I tried any solution , even those are in Stack-overflow. none of them working.

update : I don't want to use hover.

update : solution found. above code is completely correct but you should add this config to tailwind.config.js :

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      transitionProperty: {
        'height': 'height'
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't dynamically generate classes like this. Instead, your ternary should select complete class names. See "Writing purgeable HTML" in: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production.

Comment: I recently had trouble triggering transitions based on component state instead of tailwind variants. I think it's because tailwind swaps the class entirely instead of just changing the property with the transition when you're not using variants, and as a result, CSS doesn't recognize the transition. In the end, I just did that transition in regular CSS instead of tailwind and it worked fine.